# How to set nan iteratively in column based on other column value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Imagine you have the following df:

```
d = {'taxrate#1': [1, 2], 'taxrate#2': [3, np.nan],'line amount#1': [10, 20], 'line amount #2': [50, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    taxrate#1   taxrate#2   line amount#1   line amount #2
0   1             3.0           10            50.0
1   2             NaN           20            12
```

Now, I would like to set the value of line amount #2 to nan if taxrate#2 is nan. I would like to do the above iteratively/dynamically, because the line amounts/ taxrates can span up to #10.

So ideal output would be:

```
    taxrate#1   taxrate#2   line amount#1   line amount #2
0   1             3.0           10            50.0
1   2             NaN           20            NaN
```

How to achieve the above?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
>>> d = {
         'taxrate#1': [1, 2], 'taxrate#2': [3, np.nan],
         'line amount#1': [10, 20], 'line amount#2': [50, 12]
    }
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> longdf = pd.wide_to_long(
        df.reset_index(), 
        stubnames=['taxrate', 'line amount'], 
        i='index', sep='#', j='number'
    )
>>> longdf
              taxrate  line amount
index number                      
0     1           1.0           10
1     1           2.0           20
0     2           3.0           50
1     2           NaN           12

>>> longdf.loc[longdf['taxrate'].isna(), 'line amount'] = np.nan
>>> widedf = longdf.reset_index().pivot(index=['index'], columns=['number'])
>>> widedf.columns = [f'{stub}#{num}' for stub, num in widedf.columns]

>>> widedf
       taxrate#1  taxrate#2  line amount#1  line amount#2
index                                                    
0            1.0        3.0           10.0           50.0
1            2.0        NaN           20.0            NaN
```

Comment: I can't seem to overwrite the existing df, do you know why?

Comment: @Max what do you mean? `df = widedf` doesn't work?

Comment: So I want to overwrite an existing df with more values but same column names with: dftaxitems.update(widedf, overwrite = True). However it doesn't update the values..

Comment: I think its a problem because updated values are NaN and the inplace values are numbers

Comment: @Max yes, that's correct, you can not update existing non-na values with na values using `df.update`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and a loop

```
d = {'taxrate#1': [np.nan, 2], 'taxrate#2': [3, np.nan],
     'line amount#1': [10, 20], 'line amount#2': [50, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

for taxrate_col in {x for x in df.columns if x.startswith("taxrate")}:
    col_id = taxrate_col.split("#")[1]
    df.loc[df[taxrate_col].isna(), f'line amount#{col_id}'] = np.nan
```

---

That make

```
   taxrate#1  taxrate#2  line amount#1  line amount#2
0        NaN        3.0             10             50
1        2.0        NaN             20             12
```

Becomes

```
   taxrate#1  taxrate#2  line amount#1  line amount#2
0        NaN        3.0            NaN           50.0
1        2.0        NaN           20.0            NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however would like to do it dynamically because taxrates / 
 line amounts may span up to #10 lines

Comment: @Max do you mean multiple columns and not multiple lines ? So you mean lineamount1 based on taxrates1, lineamount2 base on taxrate2, ... ?

Comment: Yes sorry multiple columns! Exactly!

Comment: @Max If you can add similar sample data in question that would help you get quick right answer.